# How can I use RxJS to generate a requestAnimationFrame loop?

Tags: javascript, rxjs, rxjs5, requestanimationframe

My goal is to create an animation loop à la `requestAnimationFrame` so that I could do something like this:

```
animationObservable.subscribe(() =>
{
    // drawing code here
});
```

I tried this code as a basic test:

```
let x = 0;

Rx.Observable
    .of(0)
    .repeat(Rx.Scheduler.animationFrame)
    .takeUntil(Rx.Observable.timer(1000))
    .subscribe(() => console.log(x++));
```

[Here is a JSFiddle but I'm not liable for any browser crashes from running this.](https://jsfiddle.net/kendfrey/feb9tqar/)

I expected this to log the numbers from 0 to approximately 60 (because that is my monitor's refresh rate) over 1 second. Instead, it rapidly logs numbers (much faster than `requestAnimationFrame` would), begins to cause the page to lag, and finally overflows the stack around 10000 and several seconds later.

Why does the `animationFrame` scheduler behave this way, and what is the correct way to run an animation loop with RxJS?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's because the default behaviour of `Observable.of` is to emit immediately.

To change this behaviour, you should specify the `Scheduler` when calling `Observable.of`:

```js
let x = 0;

Rx.Observable
    .of(0, Rx.Scheduler.animationFrame)
    .repeat()
    .takeUntil(Rx.Observable.timer(1000))
    .subscribe(() => console.log(x++));
```

```html
<script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.min.js"></script>
```

Or, [more simply](https://mobile.twitter.com/BenLesh/status/901919142034284546), replace the `of` and `repeat` operators with:

```
Observable.interval(0, Rx.Scheduler.animationFrame)
```

Comment: Somehow I missed that, probably because when I first ran into the problem I wasn't using `of`, but something that behaved differently. Suddenly it's much clearer. Thanks!

Comment: I tried both interval and of + repeat and I noticed interval version emits twice for each frame, check out this stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rxjs-animationframe-bug

Comment: @pokrishka I think you should open this as a bug in the GitHub repo: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues And, maybe, reference your comment and your tweet in the issue.

Answer (score 12):

This is how I use requestAnimationFrame with rxjs. I've seen a lot of developers using 0 instead of animationFrame.now(). It's much better to pass the time because you often need that in animations.

```js
const { Observable, Scheduler } = Rx;

const requestAnimationFrame$ = Observable
  .defer(() => Observable
    .of(Scheduler.animationFrame.now(), Scheduler.animationFrame)
    .repeat()
    .map(start => Scheduler.animationFrame.now() - start)
  );

// Example usage
const duration$ = duration => requestAnimationFrame$
  .map(time => time / duration)
  .takeWhile(progress => progress < 1)
  .concat([1])

duration$(60000)
  .subscribe((i) => {
    clockPointer.style.transform = `rotate(${i * 360}deg)`;
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.3/dist/global/Rx.js"></script>

<div style="border: 3px solid black; border-radius: 50%; width: 150px; height: 150px;">
  <div id="clockPointer" style="width: 2px; height: 50%; background: black; margin-left: 50%; padding-left: -1px; transform-origin: 50% 100%;"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: That is really cool! Can you talk through the construction of the `requestAnimationFrame$` Observable?

Answer (score 4):

As of RxJs >= 5.5 you do it the following way:

```
import { animationFrameScheduler, of, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { repeat,takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

let x = 0;

    of(null, animationFrameScheduler)
      .pipe(
        repeat(),
        takeUntil(timer(1000)),
      )
      .subscribe(() => {
        console.log(x++);
      });
```

OR:

```
import { animationFrameScheduler, of, timer } from 'rxjs';
import { repeat, tap, takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

let x = 0;

of(null, animationFrameScheduler)
  .pipe(
    tap(() => {
      console.log(x++);
    }),
    repeat(),
    takeUntil(timer(1000)),
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Ben Lesh's presentation about animation in 2017](https://youtu.be/X_RnO7KSR-4?t=1110) and adjusted to RxJS 7, plus my small tweak to add time difference from last frame:

```js
let animationFrameObservable = rxjs.defer(() => {
    // using defer so startTime is set on subscribe, not now
    const startTime = rxjs.animationFrameScheduler.now();
    let lastTime = startTime;
    // using interval but not using the default scheduler
    return rxjs.interval(0, rxjs.animationFrameScheduler).pipe(
        // modify output to return elapsed time and time diff from last frame
        rxjs.map(() => {
            const currentTime = rxjs.animationFrameScheduler.now();
            const diff = currentTime - lastTime;
            lastTime = currentTime;
            return [currentTime - startTime, diff];
        }));
});

// use the observable
animationFrameObservable.pipe(
    rxjs.tap(x => console.log(x)),
    rxjs.takeUntil(rxjs.timer(10000))
).subscribe();
```